# Solr Sunspot multivalued field get matched element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm working on autocomplete functionality with solr and EdgeNGram
And create come multivalued field

here is details from schema.xml

.....

```
<fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!--tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/-->
    <!--tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50"/-->
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

.......

```
<dynamicField name="*_ac" type="autocomplete" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

That's how I declare user model

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

searchable do
    text :email
    text :name
    autocomplete :text_ac, :as => :text_ac, :multiple => true do 
       [self.email,self.name]
    end
  end

end

And what I'm looking for is the way to get "hited" value

When I'm querying solr with

```
Sunspot.search(User, Post) do with(:user_id, 1);
 adjust_solr_params do |p| p[:q] = 'text_ac:"some s"'; p[:fq] = '' end 
end.results
```

I can get instances (Users, Posts)

, but how can I get hitted values - exact row in multivalued field - element of array